# convert mercurial to git with not UTF8 characters

Tags: git, utf-8, mercurial, fastexport

I have many mercurial repositories and I try to convert them to git repo.
I used fast-export
https://github.com/frej/fast-export
and everything was good, but some of my mercurial repo have files with russian letters.
It's huge repositories with about 20k commits and many branches

on ubuntu it looks like

```
docs/
|-- Android
|-- DataContracts
|-- \302\345\355\344\356\360\373
|-- \304\340\362\340\312\356\355\362\360\340\352\362\373
|-- \310\355\361\362\360\363\352\366\350\350
|-- \310\361\365\356\344\355\340\377\ \344\356\352\363\354\345\355\362\340\366\350\377
|-- \317\360\356\362\356\352\356\353\373
`-- \320\345\353\350\347\355\340\377\ \344\356\352\363\354\345\355\362\340\366\350\377
```

on windows it looks like normal

```
Get-ChildItem .\docs\


    Каталог: C:\temp\mercurial\Ptk\docs


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Android
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                DataContracts
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Вендоры
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                ДатаКонтракты
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Инструкции
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Исходная документация
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Протоколы
d-----       12.01.2021     10:11                Релизная документация
-a----       03.03.2021     12:30              0 Вендоры2
```

inside docs folder i have many documentations in word, pdf and other format

at first i tried to convert with command

`~/mercurial/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r ~/mercurial/Ptk -fe ISO-8859-1`
but after converting characters were broken

next i tried to rename all files in my repo
https://serverfault.com/questions/319070/mercurial-convert-filename-encoding

```
import sys
for path in sys.stdin:
    old = path[:-1] # strip newline
    new = old.decode("cp1251").encode("utf-8")
    print 'rename "%s" "%s"' % (old, new)
```

$ hg manifest --all | python rename.py > rename.txt
output is

```
rename ".gitignore" ".gitignore"
rename ".hgignore" ".hgignore"
rename ".hglf/docs/����������/��������� ������������� ��� �� �������/files/android_root.exe" ".hglf/docs/Инструкции/Первичная инициализация ПТК из коробки/files/android_root.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename.py", line 4, in <module>
    new = old.decode("cp1251").encode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1251.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 12: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to use other decode cp1252

`file -ib docs/*`

output

```
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
```

next i tried to convert with  tortoisehg
https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

```
hg bookmark -r default master
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" push c:\temp\mercurial\converted-repo
```

after converting characters were broken

I don't want to delete any documentations from my repositories because not only documentations with russian characters inside repo and i have source files with russian characters, don't ask why :)

Could you give me advice how i can convert it to git repo?

Comment: Wish i knew the answer... did you post an issue on the fast-export  github?

Comment: It looks like the actual encoding is in fact CP1251, not 1252 and not 866. I get the right text (`Вендоры` ... "vendor"?) when I decode `\302\345\355\344\356\360\373` with that code page. I don't know off-hand how to convince the export tool to use the right code page, though.

Comment: yes, it's `Вендоры` right text